# Redirect domain name to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, dns, search-engine

I have theses domain names installed :

Main domaine name : [www.example.com](https://www.example.com)

Others domains : [www.example.org](https://www.example.org), [www.example.fr](https://www.example.fr), [www.animals.com](https://www.animals.com)

I first make a rule on my .htacess to redirect all traffic from theses domain names into my main domain www.example.com with the "https" :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have then a rule to rewrite my URL like that :

```
RewriteRule   ^([a-z]{2})-([0-9]+)-(.*)\.html$   index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2  [L]
```

The structure of my urls are the following :
https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html
I need to promote this page on internet, but the URL is pretty difficult to remember and my main domain name : www.example.com is to generic. So I bought the domain name : www.animals.com

So I want that my visitors arrive on this page https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html with this (easy to remember) URL : www.animals.com

I do have 2 very specific and important pages on my website that I want to promote though an easy to remember and short URL.

What is the best practice regarding Search Engines (Google) ? Is it a good idea, good practice to do it ?

Should I make a 301 redirection, so I can give to people this www.animals.com URL to visit my page, they will be then redirected and their browser will display https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html

Or is there a possibility to print www.animals.com as the URL on the browser when https://www.example.com/fr-10-my-page-about-animals.html is called ?

I would really need your advice and help regarding this topic and more informations on how to achieve it in the most Google Friendly way. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Your question is not very related to programming and since you speak about SEO and such it will probably be more ontopic on [webmasters.se] but make sure to read their help to find out what is ontopic or not and how to ask a good question (do a search too as your problem may have been already discussed). Writing tip: put your URLs in reverse quotes as they are not true links, just examples.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Webmastering/SEO and is better suited to the Webmasters Stack.